# Jquery animate doesn't work in timeOut()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to make a menu disapear after 2 sec when mouse isn't moving with .animate().

Sadly, it doesn't work as it's supposed to. It enter in the `if` (verified with console.log), but the animate just doesn't animate.

Here the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ var lastTimeMouseMoved;
$(document).mousemove(function(){
    $('#mod_logo_center').animate({top:'0'},1000);
    $(".fixed").animate({top:'0'}, 1000);
    $("#footer").animate({bottom:'0'}, 1000);
    lastTimeMouseMoved = new Date().getTime();
});
setInterval(function(){
     var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    console.log(currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved);
    if((currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved) > 2000){
        $(".fixed").animate({top:'-62'}, 1000);
        $("#footer").animate({bottom:'-32'}, 1000);
        $('#mod_logo_center').animate({top:'-128'},1000);
}}, 2000);});
```

Thanks in advance

Update :

Fixed with a boolean saying if it has moved before or not, doing the .animate on not. But the answer given below is also good !

Comment: Try with `{top:'-62px'}` instead of `{top:'-62'}`

Comment: If not set in an interval, does it work as expected? BTW, you should clear the interval if condition reached

Comment: @Brewal pixel is assumed by default

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, it does, if often work randomly after 452 seconds (number given randomly).

Comment: You should provide online sample where your issue can be check

Comment: I guess because mousemove is called many many times, so putting each animation in queue. You should debounce mousemove event for sure and/or just clear queue for each specific element in the interval callback, e.g: `$(".fixed").stop(true, false).animate({top:'-62'}, 1000);`. Or depending what you are looking for, use `$(document).one("mousemove", function(){...});`

Comment: @A.Wolff I ended up with the exact same fix after fiddling it !

Comment: @A.Wolff Sir, you're the real MVP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `onmousemove` event. It triggers multiple time animations :

```
$(document).mousemove(function(){
    // happens like 126 time a second 
    $('#mod_logo_center').animate({top:'0'},1000);
    $(".fixed").animate({top:'0'}, 1000);
    $("#footer").animate({bottom:'0'}, 1000);
    lastTimeMouseMoved = new Date().getTime();
});
```

To prevent this, you can use `.stop()` to prevent previous animations to actually happend :

```
$(document).mousemove(function(){
    $('#mod_logo_center').stop().animate({top:'0'},1000);
    $(".fixed").stop().animate({top:'0'}, 1000);
    $("#footer").stop().animate({bottom:'0'}, 1000);
    lastTimeMouseMoved = new Date().getTime();
});
```

Or you can use a better event, such as `mouseenter` on a element you want, `hover`, etc...

Comment: I'm never sure about it but as i read the DOC, using `.stop()` won't clear the queue because `false` is assumed by default. `.clearQueue()`, `.finish()` or `.stop(true)` will

Comment: seems to work yet... I made a quick and dirty fiddle that I'm too ashamed to link here

Comment: That's why i'm never sure how that works exactly. The same can be said for `.delay()` where DOC says you cannot cancel it but as i have tested it in the past (don't remember which jq version?), `.finish()` will cancel any delay.

Comment: Thanks a lot. +  @A.Wolff showed me the error, you gave me an answer whereas I found one too. Also, it answer my question, so I mark it as answer, because it is "cleaner" than mine.

Comment: @A.Wolff my understanding is that it will free some memory when passing `true` as parameter. But if I'm right, `stop()` will prevent an animation to be resumed anyway... So I'm not sure why `true` was not chosen as default

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the interval, when the if statement is validated, else this will keep firing before completion of the animations. May be that is the cause. Try this and let me know..

```
var intrvl = setInterval(function(){
     var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
     console.log(currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved);
     if((currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved) > 2000){
        clearInterval(intrvl);
        $(".fixed").animate({'top':'-62'}, 1000);
        $("#footer").animate({'bottom':'-32'}, 1000);
        $('#mod_logo_center').animate({'top':'-128'},1000);
}}, 2000);});
```

Comment: Interval callback is called each 2 seconds. Animations should run 1 second each and simultanously, so even OP should clear interval, i'm quite sure this isn't his issue here

Comment: @Sorikairo have you tried keeping the css attributes in quotation?

Comment: @Sorikairo is it even getting inside the if block? put a console.log inside if and see

Comment: @Avishek As I said in the post, I put one, and it enter in the if statement.

Comment: @Sorikairo you should really consider setting up your code in a fiddle, so we can see whats wrong, rather than making assumptions..

Answer (score 0):

We don't see your html so it's hard to tell you what's wrong. But if you animate with top and bottom your control need to be position:absolute. If they don't animate the margin instead :

```
$(".fixed").animate({"margin-top":'-62px'}, 1000);
```

**UPDATE**

Try this instead. Check 2 second after the last mouse move.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(){
    $('#mod_logo_center').animate({top:'0'},1000);
    $(".fixed").animate({top:'0'}, 1000);
    $("#footer").animate({bottom:'0'}, 1000);
    lastTimeMouseMoved = new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(function(){
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

        console.log(currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved);
        if((currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved) > 2000){
            $(".fixed").animate({top:'-62'}, 1000);
            $("#footer").animate({bottom:'-32'}, 1000);
            $('#mod_logo_center').animate({top:'-128'},1000);
        }}, 2000);});
});
```

Comment: It work for making the menu appears, position are absolute already, if often make the menu disappear as expected, but never 2 seconds after the mouse stopped moving..